# Quotient group without using First Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I want to find $Ker(b)/Im(a)$ of the following maps:

$a: \mathbb Z \bigoplus \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z \bigoplus \mathbb Z \bigoplus \mathbb Z$

$a(x,y)=(x-y,x-y,x-y) $

$b:\mathbb Z \bigoplus \mathbb Z \bigoplus \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z \bigoplus \mathbb Z$

$b(x,y,z)=(z-x,0)$

I compute that $Ker(b)=\{(x,y,x) : x,y \in \mathbb Z\}$ and $Im(a)=\{(z,z,z) : z \in \mathbb Z \}$

Hence, $Ker(b)=<(1,0,1),(0,1,0)>$ and $Im(a)=<(1,1,1)>$

At this point, I define the function

$g(x,y,z)=(x-y,y-z,z-x)$ , $(x,y,z) \in Ker(b)$.

I notice that $Ker(g)=Im(a)$ and also I find that $Im(g)=\{(k,l,-k-l) : k,l \in \mathbb Z\} = <(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1)>$

and now using the First Isomorphism Theorem I find that $Ker(b)/Im(a) \simeq Im(g)$.

My question is, is there any other way of finding the quotient group, without thinking of a map $g$ (as here) and applying the First Isomorphism Theorem? I am asking because I dont know if in every situation it is possible to find directly that kind of map.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you trying to compute (co)homology groups? The reason i am asking is because if that's the case, i am a bit concerned about the generators you have chosen.

Comment: Yes I want to compute Homology groups in order to find the induced map of a chain map. Since the map is homomorphism, I want to find the image of generators of $H_n(C_*)$  through the map $f_*$ (the image is $H_n(D_*)$

Comment: Note that the chaingroups $C_*$ have different generators in different degrees. $C_n$ is generated by formal sums of $n$-simplices for $n = 0,1,2,...$. Thus it makes little sense to have the same generators in (different) chain groups.

Comment: These groups and maps belong in the same chain complex. I want to compute this quotient group (in my problem is $H_0(C_*))$ . Then I have a  map $f_1:\mathbb Z \bigoplus \mathbb Z \bigoplus \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$. I will find the $ H_0(D_*)$ in the same way and then I will compute the induced map $f_*$. Since $f_*:H_0(C_*) \rightarrow H_0(D_*)$ with  $f_*([c])=[f_1(c)]$, I will compute the image of generators of $H_0(C_*)$ and since $f_1$ is a homomorphism I will find which is the induced map $f_*$ between these homology groups. I am sorry if i don't express the question coherently.

Comment: Still, in order to compute the respective homology groups $H_*(C_\bullet),\ H_*(D_\bullet)$ for your chain complexes $C_\bullet, D_\bullet$, you need to consider the boundary maps between your respective chain groups. I don't see how they can all have the same generators if they belong to different chain groups.